# EmailMessage(service).SendAndSaveCopy вызывает ошибку "Библиотека не зарегистрирована"

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, email

Столкнулся с ошибкой на компьютере пользователя, но не могу найти информацию, какой зависимости не хватает на рабочем месте пользователя, т.к. при выполнении данной процедуры выдается ошибка "Библиотека не зарегистрирована".

```
public static void SendMailSyncroniosly(IEnumerable<string> recipients, string subject, BodyType bodyType, string body, IEnumerable<string> attachments, bool isReadReceiptRequested)
    {
        ExchangeService service = ExchangeServiceSingleton.GetInstance();
        if (service != null)
        {
            try
            {
                _forceStop = true;
                EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service);
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = new MessageBody(bodyType, body);
                message.IsReadReceiptRequested = isReadReceiptRequested;

                // adding recipients of a email message and attachment if they exist
                foreach (string recipient in recipients)
                {
                    if (!recipient.IsEmpty())
                    {
                        message.ToRecipients.Add(recipient);
                    }
                }

                if (attachments != null)
                    foreach (string attachment in attachments)
                    {
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(attachment)) message.Attachments.AddFileAttachment(attachment);
                    }

                message.SendAndSaveCopy();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                XtraMessageBox.Show(string.Format("Произошла ошибка при отправке письма: {0}", ex.Message),
                    "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                _forceStop = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Что находится в InnerException?

Comment: В InnerException **null**

Answer (score 0):

Причина найдена - у пользователя из под которого запущена программа не было прав на доступ к ActiveDirectory (соответствующие библиотеки были недоступны, сервисы для AD остановлены) для получения EMail, из-за чего и происходила данная ошибка.